# DocuSign Connect X.509 Certificate Authentication/Security

Tags: docusignapi

How do I secure my DocuSign Connect https listener so that only requests from DocuSign are accepted?

I have read the Connect service guide and am uncleared on whether the following setting can be used for this purpose:

- Sign Message with X509 Certificate

  1. Does this setting apply to both the SOAP and HTTPS listener interfaces?
  2. Can this setting be used to secure my listener so that only DocuSign requests will be accepted?
  3. How do I set up my service to validate the signed message as valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Does this setting apply to both the SOAP and HTTPS listener interfaces?

Yes, it does indeed apply to both listener interfaces.

- Can this setting be used to secure my listener so that only DocuSign requests will be accepted?

Yes, that's what using the X509 certificates accomplishes.

- How do I set up my service to validate the signed message as valid?

It is dependent on the encryption technology you decide to use.  If you have something chosen already you should be able to go through its documentation to find out how to verify the messages.  Often times it will be binary security token in the header.

**More Info**

Additionally, please note that DocuSign uses the standard WSE3 BinarySecurityToken
in the SoapHeader to pass the certificate.

From Page #9 of the [DocuSign Connect Service Guide](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have provided my certificate to my DocuSign account manager and have enabled the option to sign message with certificate on the Connect settings page. How do I verify that the message is indeed being signed?

Comment: Also, I'm using ASP.NET. Is there a guide on the DocuSign website that I can use to get started on this task?

Comment: For a signed message sent by DocuSign Connect, I need to know where in the http request the digital signature will be included. Will it be in the headers, body, or within the DocuSignEnvelopeInformation object? I need to know where it will be included so that I can retrieve it and verify that it is a valid digital signature.

Please provide me with some sample raw data that DocuSign Connect will send for a signed message, so that I can properly identify where the digital signature is located.

Comment: Depending on your library stack, you may have support for extracting the cert from the HTTP object, but that is not the normal way of handling digitally signed messages.  Instead, you could add our public SignBy x.509 cert to your Trust Store on the server.

Comment: If you don’t care about actually digitally signing the message but just want to receive our cert and inspect it, then you can implement as a SOAP listener and check the other cert checkbox for including the cert in the SOAP Header.  This is less secure as nothing is actually signed, but it is something you can extract via your code.

Comment: Hello. I need to setup my https endpoint the same way. My server is IIS 8. I guess I have to create a self signed certificate first. What's the proper format to export it? Do I need to include the private key in the exported cert? I'm using ASP .NET WebAPI as the https listener. Do you have any sample code on how to extract the cert from the http Request object and validate it?

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work for hours - we've checked the "Sign Message with X509 Cert" option. We're using a REST listener. We are not able to extract the certificate from the request. What does this option actually do? Is the content encrypted? Is a header value added?