# Docusign Callback authentication

Tags: docusignapi

When the Docusign callback happens on any event such as Signer has signed or declined a document, how can I authenticate the call at my end.

I have a site deployed which listens to the callback from Docusign. I need to authenticate if this call is from docusign or a robot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocuSign Connect X.509 Certificate Authentication/Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953343/docusign-connect-x-509-certificate-authentication-security)

Comment: Probably not very secure but you shouldn't trust data coming from any outside point to your server anyway, but you can make your endpoint/script that docuSign calls a UUID, something like `/bf78be69-01a5-4eb4-a041-d5c5be4dd606.php`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a duplicate question, one popular method is using X509 Certificates. See the following thread:

[DocuSign Connect X.509 Certificate Authentication/Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953343/docusign-connect-x-509-certificate-authentication-security)